# Visual Basic 2010 - Creating a Silverlight project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, installation, silverlight-5.0

**Hello,**

My operating system is **Windows 7 - SP1 (64bit)**. I tried to create a Silverlight project in *Visual Basic 2010 (Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - SP1)*. Complete Install expect *SQL Server 2008 Express SP1 (x64)*. But I got this message,

[image: You need to install Silverlight 3 SDK before creating a SIlverlight project. Download the SDK at: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=143525]

So I went to that link shown above ([here it is](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=143525)) and downloaded the [Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18149) and tried to install it and this is the message I get,

[image]

The link in the above message leads [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=177432). What needs to be done here to create a Silverlight project in Visual Basic 2010?

Comment: I got this problem and the only solution was uninstall everything related to silverlight and them install only to last framework. For example: Uninstall silverlight sdk, tools and every single thing, then install silverlight 5 for example.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your information. I already did exactly that. Uninstalled everything related to Silverlight and then installed Silverlight 5. What I explained in my question is after I tried that.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eea2a8bf-42c7-46a2-ad4f-664ccab0eb27/help-cant-create-or-open-silverlight-projects-visual-studio-has-been-screwed-by-sl5?forum=vssetup . Check this out, apparently to problem could be on .NET Framework as well. Which version do you have?

Comment: I have .NET Frameworks: 2.0 (SP2) Compact, 3.5 Compact, 4 (Multi-Targeting Pack), 4.5.1

Comment: Then try to uninstall it and then reinstall only the latest one

Comment: Uninstall all versions or just the version 4.0 and 4.5.1? Because, I tired the second one and it did not work.

Comment: Please see this link too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749258/vb-net-2010-silverlight-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [Vinicius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141477/vinicius) for the help in above comments.

This is what I did. I went to ***Programs and Features*** in **Control Panel** and uninstalled everything with the term "*Visual Studio 2010*". Then installed Visual Studio 2010 again. That's it. It worked. It created the Silverlight project with *Silverlight 3*. I also installed [Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18149) after that and it created the project.